# how to get textbox value from row of a gridview xaml

Tags: xaml, gridview

I bind a list of  jobtype values to a gridview, each row have sno,jobtype,check box,and a text box.   when a check box is checked the text box will enable, and I have to enter some value(like fee) here I can check multiple jobtypes,and enter fee in text box, and finally save these values( jobtype, fee)     I successfully bind the data, but how to get that entered value from text box of each row?? And how can I enable or disable text box on checked or unchecked the check box.. Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You cant have JobType as the DataContext for row.

You need to build a wrapper around it, that will contain JobType, and the other strings you wish your TextBoxes to Bind to.

Your list of JobTypes should be a list of that wrapper.